# Python: how to calculate data received and send between two ipaddresses and ports

Tags: routing, python, socket, network-traffic

I guess it's socket programming. But I have never done socket programming expect for running the tutorial examples while learning Python. I need some more ideas to implement this.

What I specifically need is to run a monitoring program of a server which will poll or listen to traffic being exchange from different IPs across different popular ports. 
For example, how do I get data received and sent through port 80 of 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.1 ( which is the gateway).

I checked out a number of ready made tools like MRTG, Bwmon, Ntop etc but since we are looking at doing some specific pattern studies, we need to do data capturing within the program.

Idea is to monitor some popular ports and do a study of network traffic across some periods and compare them with some other data.

We would like to figure a way to do all this with Python....

Comment: You'll probably get a much better answer to this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need data in realtime or not? If not, you can try dumping the data to file with tcpdump (with appropriate filters), and analyzing the content after. I think python has good-enough (lib)pcap support.

If you need realtime, you have to check if python is capable of packat capture with pcap (should be), without interfering with the traffic flow (should be).

So the first step would be too google 'python pcap', and finding the easiest wrapper for it all.

With that, you get raw packets, and you can parse them any way you wish.